# How to identify the HTTP methods supported by a web server?

Tags: webserver, http

How can I identify the different HTTP methods supported by a web server, like OPTIONS, TRACE, etc.?

I have tried the [nc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) command on Linux. But it doesn't work. It doesn't show me the HTTP methods supported, some other HTTP headers are returned along with the requested HTML page. Is there another solution?

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that different methods may be supported by different resources.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), the OPTIONS method *should* return the supported methods. Keyword is *should* since this isn't always the case. As the prior posts have already pointed out each method needs to be tested separately to be sure.

Comment: What if the `OPTIONS` method is not among the supported methods?

Comment: @Brandon: If the OPTIONS method isn't supported that means the server doesn't support enumerating available methods in the standard way. In other word, you're screwed anyway. A server that doesn't support the standard's prescribed way of doing things may still be capable of doing it through a non standard way, but a generic HTTP client wouldn't be able to venture a guess of what that way will be, since the server isn't standard compliant. You'll have to make do with poke and see.

Answer (score 8):

As there are only few methods (OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE and CONNECT), you can use a script and nc to send a request to all allowed methods and parse the results:

```
for method in OPTIONS GET HEAD POST PUT DELETE TRACE CONNECT ; do 
    echo -e "\n\nTrying $method\n\n" 
    echo -e "$method / HTTP/1.1\nHost: server-hostname\nConnection: close\n\n" | nc server-hostname 80 | head 
    sleep 2
done
```

HTTP errors 400, 403, 405 and 406 generally are the types returned when trying to use a not implemented method.

Comment: Is that trying to `DELETE` the path `/`, just to find out whether it works?

Comment: Yes, that's the thing I am feared about. What if `DELETE` is supported? Will it delete it?

Comment: Getting an error does *not* mean that the method is not implemented... For example, if I get a 400 or 403 for `POST`, I will not think "Oh `POST` must not be supported", I will think "Duh, what data should I put in the HTTP content?"

Comment: When a webserver supports the DELETE method on the domain root without any form of authentication, the admin is obviously clueless. Unfortunately many lawyers, prosecutors, judges and jurys are equally clueless, so getting a subpoena for computer sabotage isn't completely implausible. Keep in mind that PUT can be equally destructive.

Comment: Shouldn't this be checking for the error code `501 Not Implemented`?

Comment: You should look for `501` too, but as long as I can tell, the majority of servers don't display `501 Not Implemented`, but `405 Method not allowed` instead.

Comment: Also, the list of HTTP methods is maintained in the [HTTP Method Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml). There are 38 methods in total, most of them defined by WebDAV.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to identify the methods supported by a web server is to try each one and evaluate the response to determine if it indicates the method is supported or not.  You can't simply query to ask which methods it supports; it won't give you a list.

That said, there are better tools than nc.  [Nmap and metasploit](http://eromang.zataz.com/2010/09/18/http-methods-scanning-differences-between-metasploit-and-nmap/) both support HTTP method scanning and essentially automate the work for you.

Comment: No, you *can* simply query it, and it *may* give you a list.

Comment: using Nikto vulnerability scanner is another way to determine methods in place + Allowed HTTP Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD, TRACE

Answer (score 2):

There are circumstances where a HTTP server will return a list of supported methods for a given resource in its [`Allow` response header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.4.1), according to [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) (the *new* RFC for HTTP 1.1 semantics):

- First in the response to an [`OPTIONS` request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.7), either on a specific resource path, or on the special `*` path (which would mainly describe the capabilities of the server);
- Second, if a method which is known, but not supported by the server on a given resource is tried, the server can respond with a [405 Method Not Allowed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5) status code; in that case, it *must* give the list of allowed methods in the [`Allow` response header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.4.1);
- For any other HTTP request, the origin server is allowed to return a list of supported methods in the [`Allow` response header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.4.1);

But what if the server does not cooperate? E.g. you have tried an `OPTIONS *` request, various `GET` requests, and the server never returns a list of allowed methods in an `Allow` header? Or what if the server replies, but you suspect that it is lying?

Then you do not know, and you will have to live with it. What you will do will depend on your goal:

- If you are simply trying to use the target system, you should do the cautious thing by assuming that only `GET` is supported, *and* obtain more documentation about how to use the system;
- If you are doing penetration testing, then you can test all the known verbs, test some less known ones (such as [`PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789)) or even invent some of your own; more generally, part of the test would be throwing garbage at the system to see how it reacts;

However, think about *why* you want to know the list of supported verbs - because without additional data, knowing which verbs are used is close to useless (e.g. I know that `https://accounts.google.com/AddSession` accepts the `POST` verb - what good does simply knowing the verb do to me if I do not know what data should be in, in what format, etc.?)